# How to I optimize this LED circuit?

Tags: led, resistors, led-driver, thermal, optimization

### The Project

This part is pretty simple: I'm building a stunt lightsaber up from scratch. The led is held in a heatsink housing inside a 1 inch (internal diameter) aluminum tube. The heatsink is rated **3 watts**. I'll be using either a **6v** or **3.7v** power supply. The LED I've selected is the **[Cree XLamp XP-E2 Color High Power LED Star](https://www.ledsupply.com/leds/cree-xlamp-xp-e2-color-high-power-led-star)** in **Green**. It comes in a **one-up** or **three-up** configuration, has a max drive current of **1000mA**, a forward voltage of **3.2v at 350mA** or **3.7v at 1000mA**, and a thermal resistance of **5°C/W**.

### The Question(s)

As I understand it, you either have to wire an LED in series with a resistor to protect it, or power it using a an LED driver. My questions are:

1. What resistance/driver amperage do I need to maximize brightness without damaging the LED?
2. Would I see better results using the 3-up version versus the 1-up version?
3. Is there something I've missed completely here that I need to consider?

Also, if anyone could be so kind as to come up with a circuit diagram, it would help me out a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts to learn here.

The LED internal junction voltage is sensitive to heat so a 3W heat source to a 3W heatsink might rise say 60'C on the internal junction if done right then the internal voltage lowers and it draws more current if the source is constant. (.e.g. -4 mV/'C rise x 40'C = -240 mV per LED)

Then the internal LEDs also have bulk resistance which causes the rise in Vf (3.2 to 3.7) with current rising from 350 to 1000 mA. Thus for those conditions we can say the internal bulk resistance of that is R= (3.7-3.2V)/(1000-350)mA= 0.5/0.65 or just slightly less than 1 Ohm.  But if you compare typ. to max. Vf, you can see a large tolerance in the R in mass production.

So by adding a small resistance in series, your supply needs to be a higher voltage. But if your supply is a 3.7V battery, there is a need to regulate that somehow such as a buck-boost converter used in smart torches. But using a 6V battery wastes energy and heat in series unless you use a buck converter with 90 % efficiency.

Now all batteries like all LEDs also have bulk resistance which in both cases the resistance is inverse to it's power capacity.  But every  chemistry has unique values and quality also makes a difference with lower values.

So the 2 concepts are the LED NTC or negative temperature coefficient of lower forward voltage with rising temperature (thermometer effect) and the bulk resistance that varies with power of LED and quality from typ to max. and similarly for the battery. The battery has an effective series resistance (ESR) and also declines in voltage slightly with the state of charge (SoC) .  (OK maybe 3 concepts) ;)

Thus defining a solution depends on your expectations, simple, efficient, cheap or max brightness and power with a regulator and added cost/complexity. For example a cooler 3W LED is better to use a 10W heatsink or more like a CPU heatsink with more surface area. As this high temperature rise affects LED life more than transistors. (4th concept)

Once you define your goals, expectations , budget and priorities, then compromises and a solution is easier to match.